# Pythonbrew can't build python 2.6

Tags: python, linux, pythonbrew

I've tried to install python from pythonbrew as the tutorial for SublimeClang told me. I've executed the command `sudo ./pythonbrew install --configure="--enable-unicode=ucs4" 2.6` (tried both with and without sudo). It says to check logs/build.log. I don't see any problems

```
patching file Makefile.pre.in
patching file setup.py
Hunk #1 succeeded at 15 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 309 (offset 66 lines).
patching file Modules/_ssl.c
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux3
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... i686
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for g++... g++
configure: WARNING:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for AIX... no
checking for --with-suffix... 
checking for case-insensitive build directory... no
checking LIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION).a
checking LINKCC... $(PURIFY) $(MAINCC)
checking for --enable-shared... no
checking for --enable-profiling... 
checking LDLIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION).a
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ar... ar
checking for svnversion... not-found
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for --with-pydebug... no
checking whether gcc accepts -fno-strict-aliasing... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -OPT:Olimit=0... no
checking whether gcc accepts -Olimit 1500... no
checking whether gcc supports ParseTuple __format__... no
checking whether pthreads are available without options... no
checking whether gcc accepts -Kpthread... no
checking whether gcc accepts -Kthread... no
checking whether gcc accepts -pthread... yes
checking whether g++ also accepts flags for thread support... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking asm/types.h usability... yes
checking asm/types.h presence... yes
checking for asm/types.h... yes
checking conio.h usability... no
checking conio.h presence... no
checking for conio.h... no
checking curses.h usability... no
checking curses.h presence... no
checking for curses.h... no
checking direct.h usability... no
checking direct.h presence... no
checking for direct.h... no
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking grp.h usability... yes
checking grp.h presence... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking ieeefp.h usability... no
checking ieeefp.h presence... no
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking io.h usability... no
checking io.h presence... no
checking for io.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking ncurses.h usability... no
checking ncurses.h presence... no
checking for ncurses.h... no
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking process.h usability... no
checking process.h presence... no
checking for process.h... no
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking shadow.h usability... yes
checking shadow.h presence... yes
checking for shadow.h... yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking stropts.h usability... yes
checking stropts.h presence... yes
checking for stropts.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking thread.h usability... no
checking thread.h presence... no
checking for thread.h... no
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking sys/audioio.h usability... no
checking sys/audioio.h presence... no
checking for sys/audioio.h... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h usability... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h presence... no
checking for sys/bsdtty.h... no
checking sys/epoll.h usability... yes
checking sys/epoll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... yes
checking sys/event.h usability... no
checking sys/event.h presence... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/loadavg.h usability... no
checking sys/loadavg.h presence... no
checking for sys/loadavg.h... no
checking sys/lock.h usability... no
checking sys/lock.h presence... no
checking for sys/lock.h... no
checking sys/mkdev.h usability... no
checking sys/mkdev.h presence... no
checking for sys/mkdev.h... no
checking sys/modem.h usability... no
checking sys/modem.h presence... no
checking for sys/modem.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/poll.h usability... yes
checking sys/poll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/termio.h usability... no
checking sys/termio.h presence... no
checking for sys/termio.h... no
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking sys/wait.h usability... yes
checking sys/wait.h presence... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking pty.h usability... yes
checking pty.h presence... yes
checking for pty.h... yes
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking netpacket/packet.h usability... yes
checking netpacket/packet.h presence... yes
checking for netpacket/packet.h... yes
checking sysexits.h usability... yes
checking sysexits.h presence... yes
checking for sysexits.h... yes
checking bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth.h... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth/bluetooth.h... no
checking linux/tipc.h usability... yes
checking linux/tipc.h presence... yes
checking for linux/tipc.h... yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking whether sys/types.h defines makedev... yes
checking for term.h... no
checking for linux/netlink.h... yes
checking for clock_t in time.h... yes
checking for makedev... yes
checking Solaris LFS bug... no
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for int... yes
checking size of int... 4
checking for long... yes
checking size of long... 4
checking for void *... yes
checking size of void *... 4
checking for short... yes
checking size of short... 2
checking for float... yes
checking size of float... 4
checking for double... yes
checking size of double... 8
checking for fpos_t... yes
checking size of fpos_t... 16
checking for size_t... (cached) yes
checking size of size_t... 4
checking for pid_t... (cached) yes
checking size of pid_t... 4
checking for long long support... yes
checking for long long... yes
checking size of long long... 8
checking for long double support... yes
checking for long double... yes
checking size of long double... 12
checking for _Bool support... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking for uintptr_t... (cached) yes
checking size of uintptr_t... 4
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... yes
checking size of time_t... 4
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 4
checking for --enable-toolbox-glue... no
checking for --enable-framework... no
checking for dyld... no
checking SO... .so
checking LDSHARED... $(CC) -shared
checking CCSHARED... -fPIC
checking LINKFORSHARED... -Xlinker -export-dynamic
checking CFLAGSFORSHARED... 
checking SHLIBS... $(LIBS)
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for library containing sem_init... -lpthread
checking for textdomain in -lintl... no
checking for t_open in -lnsl... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for --with-libs... no
checking for --with-system-ffi... 
checking for --with-signal-module... yes
checking for --with-dec-threads... no
checking for --with-threads... yes
checking if PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM is supported... yes
checking for pthread_sigmask... yes
checking if --enable-ipv6 is specified... yes
checking if RFC2553 API is available... yes
checking ipv6 stack type... linux-glibc
checking for OSX 10.5 SDK or later... no
checking for --with-doc-strings... yes
checking for --with-tsc... no
checking for --with-pymalloc... yes
checking for --with-wctype-functions... no
checking for dlopen... yes
checking DYNLOADFILE... dynload_shlib.o
checking MACHDEP_OBJS... MACHDEP_OBJS
checking for alarm... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for getitimer... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for chown... yes
checking for clock... yes
checking for confstr... yes
checking for ctermid... yes
checking for execv... yes
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for fchown... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for fpathconf... yes
checking for ftime... yes
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking for getgroups... yes
checking for getlogin... yes
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for getpeername... yes
checking for getpgid... yes
checking for getpid... yes
checking for getpriority... yes
checking for getpwent... yes
checking for getspnam... yes
checking for getspent... yes
checking for getsid... yes
checking for getwd... yes
checking for kill... yes
checking for killpg... yes
checking for lchmod... no
checking for lchown... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for mkfifo... yes
checking for mknod... yes
checking for mktime... yes
checking for mremap... yes
checking for nice... yes
checking for pathconf... yes
checking for pause... yes
checking for plock... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for pthread_init... no
checking for putenv... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for setegid... yes
checking for seteuid... yes
checking for setgid... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for setregid... yes
checking for setreuid... yes
checking for setsid... yes
checking for setpgid... yes
checking for setpgrp... yes
checking for setuid... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for siginterrupt... yes
checking for sigrelse... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for tcgetpgrp... yes
checking for tcsetpgrp... yes
checking for tempnam... yes
checking for timegm... yes
checking for times... yes
checking for tmpfile... yes
checking for tmpnam... yes
checking for tmpnam_r... yes
checking for truncate... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for utimes... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for wait3... yes
checking for wait4... yes
checking for wcscoll... yes
checking for _getpty... no
checking for chroot... yes
checking for link... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for fchdir... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for epoll... yes
checking for kqueue... no
checking for ctermid_r... no
checking for flock... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for true... true
checking for inet_aton in -lc... yes
checking for chflags... no
checking for lchflags... no
checking for inflateCopy in -lz... no
checking for hstrerror... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for setgroups... yes
checking for openpty... no
checking for openpty in -lutil... yes
checking for forkpty... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for fseek64... no
checking for fseeko... yes
checking for fstatvfs... yes
checking for ftell64... no
checking for ftello... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for getpgrp... yes
checking for setpgrp... (cached) yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for major... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking getaddrinfo bug... good
checking for getnameinfo... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct stat.st_flags... no
checking for struct stat.st_gen... no
checking for struct stat.st_birthtime... no
checking for struct stat.st_blocks... yes
checking for time.h that defines altzone... no
checking whether sys/select.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for addrinfo... yes
checking for sockaddr_storage... yes
checking whether char is unsigned... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for working signed char... yes
checking for prototypes... yes
checking for variable length prototypes and stdarg.h... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking if sockaddr has sa_len member... no
checking whether va_list is an array... no
checking for gethostbyname_r... yes
checking gethostbyname_r with 6 args... yes
checking for __fpu_control... yes
checking for --with-fpectl... no
checking for --with-libm=STRING... default LIBM="-lm"
checking for --with-libc=STRING... default LIBC=""
checking whether tanh preserves the sign of zero... yes
checking for hypot... yes
checking for acosh... yes
checking for asinh... yes
checking for atanh... yes
checking for copysign... yes
checking for expm1... yes
checking for finite... yes
checking for isinf... yes
checking for isnan... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for wchar_t... yes
checking size of wchar_t... 4
checking for UCS-4 tcl... no
checking whether wchar_t is signed... yes
checking what type to use for unicode... unsigned long
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether right shift extends the sign bit... yes
checking for getc_unlocked() and friends... yes
checking how to link readline libs... none
checking for rl_callback_handler_install in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_pre_input_hook in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_completion_display_matches_hook in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_completion_matches in -lreadline... no
checking for broken nice()... no
checking for broken poll()... no
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... (cached) yes
checking for working tzset()... yes
checking for tv_nsec in struct stat... yes
checking for tv_nsec2 in struct stat... no
checking whether mvwdelch is an expression... no
checking whether WINDOW has _flags... no
checking for is_term_resized... no
checking for resize_term... no
checking for resizeterm... no
checking for /dev/ptmx... yes
checking for /dev/ptc... no
checking for %zd printf() format support... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for build directories... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile.pre
config.status: creating Modules/Setup.config
config.status: creating pyconfig.h
creating Modules/Setup
creating Modules/Setup.local
creating Makefile
```

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out I haven't yet installed build-essentials

Answer (score 0):

I recommend pythonz which is a fork of pythonbrew https://github.com/saghul/pythonz

Also there is a known problem with python2.6 and recent openssl distribution. I'm using this command/tarball:

```
pythonz install 2.6.8 --url=https://bitbucket.org/schmichael/cpython-v2.6.8-nosslv2/get/v2.6.8~nosslv2.tar.gz
```